# Units of the SVG translate transform function

Tags: svg, pixel, translate

What are the units of `translate` transform function coordinates? So when i am doing `translate(100 100)` am i moving the shape 100 **pixels** to the right and to the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

## Units in svg

Unit in svg are an internal value.

Its a bit [complex](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units) to explain, but i'll try to keep it short.

All values in svg (with exceptions) are units, they are used in the viewBox.
The viewBox can be define with any number in the x and y axis.

So lets say you a viewBox of 100 x 100. (written like viewBox="0 0 100 100")
A single unit will be a value mapped to the 100 by 100 space.

So if you say: `<rect width="10" height="10" />` this will cover 10 units of 100 units in both the x and y axis.

### Why cant we just use pixel sizes?

All vector based images are made so you can show them in any size you want.
The svg with different sizes would be display differently when depending on its pixel value. This would break any svg image if scaled.

And thats why the units are used, so you have a range that will always display the same cordinates even if its scaled.

Comment: Is it not also possible to write `rect width="10px"`?

Comment: @amirt I believe it is, they get translated to units. I would avoid writing px where possible it can get confusing.

Comment: So if i also have something like the `horiz-adv-x` attribute of a svg font's glyph, could i convert it to pixels by multiplying it's value by 16, since 1 em = 16 pixels?

Comment: em = font size of the element. Be careful when using relative sizes.